# error while executing shell using if-else

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I'm trying to run a shell script defining if-else statement. This function would run a command and provide the output of ARN in the format of `arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxx:secret:/wsg/rs/INDV/XXX/test/secret`. If it unable to retrieve the ARN or throw the error msg listed below
`An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DescribeSecret operation: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.`, it supposes to provide me the update

Here my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +e

SECRET_JSON_VALUE=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $BusinessUnit/$LineOfBusiness/${ProjectName}/${ContextPath}application_$Tier --query "ARN" --output text)

if [ "$SECRET_JSON_VALUE" == "$SECRET_JSON_VALUE" ]; then
         echo "---updating the secret---"
else
        echo "---Provision a new secret---"
fi
```

It always tries to run `if` condition ie. `echo "---updating the secret---"` no matter if there is no ARN value. I want to make sure that if above command throws an error, it suppose to execute `else` condition and if above command gets the ARN Value, it suppose to execute `if` condition

Comment: sooo `[ "$SECRET_JSON_VALUE" == "$SECRET_JSON_VALUE" ]`  the same thing is always going to be equal to itself, I do not understand. `throws an error` Check the exit status `if value=$(aws ....); then echo "success"; else echo "failure"; fi`

Comment: Also, `==` isn't guaranteed to work in `[` at all (bash's built-in `[` supports it, but not all versions do). Only use `=` for string comparison -- see the relevant POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: Anyhow, the error given is from `aws secretmanager`, not from the `if/else`. And yes, even `[ "" = "" ]` is true, so how/why would that comparison _ever_ be false?

Comment: that's correct, if error comes from aws secretmanager, it supposes to run else statement which supposes to create a secret under else condition

Comment: Why do you think your code is written to go to the else if there's an error? What part of the code makes that happen?

Comment: ...to make it do that, you'd need to write it the way KamilCuk's first comment suggests, so the `if` is checking the exit status of secretmanager itself, instead of checking whether the secretmanager is equal to itself (which is always true no matter what).

Comment: the above command will validate if secrets are available. If it's available, it will provide it's ARN value. and then using if statemnet i can go ahead and update the existing secret. Else if command throws an error that means there is no secret and then using if statment it will provision a new secret

Comment: ...remember, the way an `if` works is `if CONDITION; then CONDITION-WAS-TRUE; else CONDITION-WAS-FALSE; fi` -- it only looks at if `CONDITION` was true, not at whether some random thing that happened before the `if` even started was true. In this case, your `aws secretmanager` is not inside the CONDITION place, so the `if` doesn't care if it succeeded or not.

Comment: nit: if is *not* `if CONDITION`.  It is `if COMMAND`.

Comment: I'm happy to be paraphrasing for easier comprehension here, instead of quoting the spec exactly. "The condition is an arbitrary compound command whose exit status is checked to determine how to branch" is an easy enough explanation to provide if it comes up.